# Cron Job - delete zip files from a specific directory

Tags: php, joomla, cron, cron-task

I am trying o delete all `zip` and `rar` files from a specific directory.
I have set the cron to run a PHP file called `cron.php`, which is is located in a Joomla module directory. For test purposes, I have set the cron job time to 5 minutes.

I also put a zip file in the directory called `test.zip`

**Command:**

```
php /home/MYUSER/public_html/MYSITE/modules/mod_module_gen/cron.php
```

**PHP:** Note: "MYSITE" is the subdomain the site is located

```
<?php
$dir = "/home/MYUSER/public_html/MYSITE/modules/mod_module_gen/package";
$files = scandir($dir);

foreach ($files as $file) {                   
   if(preg_match("/\.(zip|rar)$/", $file)){
        unlink($file);
   }                    
} 
?>
```

However every 5 minutes, the error log keeps on throwing the following errors:

```
PHP Warning:  unlink(test.zip) [<a href='function.unlink'>function.unlink</a>]: No such file or directory in /home/MYUSER/public_html/MYSITE/modules/mod_module_gen/cron.php on line 18
```

Not sure why this error is occurring as the file **does** exist. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably because the file it's trying to unlink doesn't exist (incorrect path), can you try dumping $file

Comment: This crazy, making a cron job to let php delete files. How about the shell?

Comment: @JvdBerg - I only chose php cause I thought it might be easier. However if you can point me in the right direction for a shell command only then that would be great. thanks

Comment: `rm <filename>` filename can be a mask also. If you fidlle with it it is doable in a single line command. For rm see http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_rm.htm

Comment: something like: `find /home/MYUSER/public_html/MYSITE/modules/mod_module_gen/package/*.zip -name -exec rm -rf () \;`

Comment: @JvdBerg - thankyou, will also give this a go

Comment: Think the problem is your working directory. unlink($dir . $file);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the current directory is treated as where the PHP script is **run from**.

So the files are in:

`/home/MYUSER/public_html/MYSITE/modules/mod_module_gen/package`

but the command (once `$file` is resolved) to delete is:

`unlink('test.zip');`

As the file is being run from somewhere else (say `~`):

PHP is trying to unlink `~/test.zip`

Consider doing

`unlink($dir.'/'.$file)`

Comment: Thankyou! silly of me to forget to add the path in the unlink() command

Answer (score 1):

you are passing only file names here mate

```
unlink('/home/MYUSER/public_html/MYSITE/modules/mod_module_gen/package/'.$file);
```

Answer (score 1):

scandir returns an array of filenames in $dir, but doesn't include the path itself.... you're trying to unset the filename; but unless $dir is your current working directory it is only by happenstance that it might work if there was a file of the same name in your cwd.